# Use of "hasNext()" in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while(input.hasNext())
{ 
    System.out.println(input.nextInt());
    System.out.println("To go on,Enter any number");    
}
```

How does `hasNext()` statement run here? Can anyone explain it detailedly?

Comment: Which part of the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) is unclear to you?

Comment: The condition inside the `while` statement runs at the beginning of the first iteration, and at the beginning of each subsequent iteration of the enclosing loop.

Comment: Note that `hasNext` returns true if there's any non-whitespace input remaining, even if it isn't a number.  Thus, it's possible that `nextInt` could throw an exception.  `Scanner` also has a `hasNextInt` method to see if there's another token and it looks like an integer.  You can use both, i.e. use `hasNext()` first to see if there's any input remaining, and then `hasNextInt()` to make sure it's a valid integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hasNext() tells you whether there are more elements to be read from the stream. In this case, the call will block until there is user input.

There are three scenarios:

1. User provides no input at all. The call will block indefinitely.
2. User provides some input that is not EOF. The return value will be
   true.
3. User inputs EOF. The return value will be false.

In the context of your program, it means that the while-loop will be executed until the user provides EOF (Ctrl+D or Ctrl+Z). If the user is aware of that, I suppose it will be fine.

But the behavior could definitely be made more user friendly: for example, it currently asks the user to enter a number. But hasNext() doesn't care if the input is number or not, the loop will continue forever as long as the input is not EOF.

Another problem could arise if the user tries to provide some predefined input through the command line, if the input is not specifically terminated with an EOF the program will block forever. The statement does **not** mean the program will quit when there is no more input to be read (unless specified by EOF, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29), `hasNext()`:

- Is specified in interface `Iterator<String>`
- Returns `true` if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input
- Throws `IllegalStateException` if this scanner is closed

In your code, `hasNext()` is used in order to check whether there are any more elements to iterate in your iterateable collection, after each `while` iteration is complete.

Comment: Could you please add a comment to my answer if downvoted? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner` class according to documentation implements a class  `Iterator<String>`

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

If your class implements an `Iterator<T>` then it needs to implement the following functions

- hasNext

**Returns true if the iteration has more elements. (In other words, returns true if next() would return an element rather than throwing an exception.)**

Specific to Scanner the doc specifies:

**Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.**

- next

**Returns the next element in the iteration.**

- remove

  Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next(). The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

Source: [Iterator doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Comment: This really does not answer the question.  While `Scanner` implements `Iterator`, I've never actually seen it used as an iterator.  The questioner wants to know what the behavior of `hasNext()` is with respect to how a `Scanner` functions, and this answer goes on about iterators without any information about `Scanner`.

Comment: the question simply asks about hasNext statement which is an implementation of the iterator class. and I answer the question in bold : returns true if iteration has more elements

Comment: I added the hasNext implementation specific to scanner

Answer (score 0):

Scanner scans through your whole user input it receives. So basically proper coding standards focus on how you handle unexpected situations. So hasNext() method basically checks for the whitespace or break line after the current position and checks for the binary values present after that. If present it returns true and if not returns false.